How to encrypt a file with Yubikey with openssl
I try to encrypt a file with my Yubkey and openssl on linux. My YubiKey is a
  idProduct          0x0407 Yubikey 4/5 OTP+U2F+CCID
  bcdDevice            5.24

First I extract my Public key from my yubikey:
 pkcs15-tool --read-public-key 01 -o pubkey

I get a file which reads like this:
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZ[...]WpqK
qezLU6KBlk9[...]eRDFZEkvptllFFkw==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----


When I try to encrypt a file with this public key I get an error:
openssl pkeyutl -encrypt -pubin -inkey pubkey -in file -out file.enc 
pkeyutl: Error initializing context
40A7F0A3DA720000:error:03000096:digital envelope routines:evp_pkey_asym_cipher_init:operation not supported for this keytype:../crypto/evp/asymcipher.c:189:

I recently switched to a yubikey. Before I had a epass2000 which worked this way. I can't find any proper docs for the yubikey online.
How do I encrypt a file with openssl and yubikey?
